# Does boost asio io_service guarantee execution of two parallel call chains?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In my program, using boost asio io_service, I want to have two parallel call chains. Two endless loops writing and reading to two usb ports. But does boost asio io_service guarantee execution of two parallel call chains? Look at this minimal example:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <functional>

class Chain
{
public:
    Chain(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, const std::string &message)
        : io_service(io_service)
        , message(message)
    {}

    void call()
    {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        io_service.post(std::bind(&Chain::call, this));
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service &io_service;
    std::string message;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    Chain chain1(io_service, "1");
    Chain chain2(io_service, "2");

    chain1.call();
    chain2.call();

    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
1
2
1
2
1
...
```

because current io_service implementation is fifo dispatcher. Is it guarenteed in the future it will not prints

```
1
1
1
1
1
...
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `io_service` currently makes no guarantees about the invocation order of handlers.  Thus, the `io_service` could choose to invoke only a single call chain.  Currently, only a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) specifies guarantees.

With that said, I would not worry too much about the `io_service` currently not making the guarantee.  As Asio is [on track of becoming the standard networking library](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2014/06/214809.php), one can imagine that handler scheduling will be defined throughout the specification process.  In particular, the `io_service`'s usage of the proposed executors and schedulers should provide specific guarantees as to the scheduling behavior and its options.