# Weird output for a tutorial in boost asio doc

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

In the 5th tutorial, of which the code I have given at bottom of the question, asio documentation introduced the output comes as follows :

```
Timer 2: 0
Timer 1: 1
Timer 2: 2
Timer 1: 3
Timer 2: 4
.
.
.
```

After the first one it is as expectable, with the sequence.
But even though Timer1 is wrapped in the strand first, why does Timer 2 starts running first ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

class printer
{
    public:
        printer(asio::io_service& io)
            : strand_(io),
            timer1_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
            timer2_(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1)),
            count_(0)
        {
            timer1_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this)));
            timer2_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this)));
        }

        ~printer()
        {
            std::cout << "Final count is " << count_ << "\n";
        }

        void print1()
        {
            if (count_ < 10)
            {
                std::cout << "Timer 1: " << count_ << "\n";
                ++count_;
                timer1_.expires_at(timer1_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
                timer1_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print1, this)));
            }
        }
        void print2()
        {
            if (count_ < 10)
            {
                std::cout << "Timer 2: " << count_ << "\n";
                ++count_;
                timer2_.expires_at(timer2_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
                timer2_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&printer::print2, this)));
            }
        }
private:
    asio::strand strand_;
    asio::deadline_timer timer1_;
    asio::deadline_timer timer2_;
    int count_;
};

int main()
{
    asio::io_service io;
    printer p(io);
    asio::thread t(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io));
    io.run();
    t.join();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, is it possible that I didnt get strand right? Does strand actually mind the sequence of the wrapping, or does it just ensure that these timers dont run concurrently ?

Comment: Wild guess: remove the `io.run()` from `main`; the thread `t` already calls it. That looks like a race condition, which could make funny things possible.

Comment: That is the point of the tutorial though. It shows how strand makes it possible to run io.run() from multiple threads. Of course when you remove thread t, everything acts normal.

Answer (score 1):

A [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) is used to provide serial execution of *handlers*.  Also, under certain conditions, it provides a guarantee on the order of invocation of *handlers* posted or dispatched through the strand.  The example does not meet these conditions.  Furthermore, there is no guarantee that one will observe the alternating pattern between the completion handlers.

---

IO Objects, such as timers, are not wrapped by strands, completion handlers are.  A `strand` can be thought of as being associated with a FIFO queue of handlers. If a handler queue has no handlers currently posted into an `io_service`, then it will pop one handler from itself and post it into the associated `io_service`. This flow guarantees that handlers posted into the same strand will not be invoked concurrently.

- [`strand.post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/post.html) enqueues a handler into the strand.
- [`strand.dispatch()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html) will run the handler if the current caller is running within the context of the strand.  Otherwise, it will enqueue the handler as if by `post()`.
- [`strand.wrap()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) return a new completion handler that, when invoked, will `dispatch()` the wrapped handler into the strand.  Essentially, `wrap()` defers the dispatching of a handler into the strand.

Given completion handlers `a` and `b`, if `a` is enqueued before `b`, then `a` will be invoked before `b`.  This is the fundamental guarantee to which all scenarios can be reduced.  The scenarios in which `a` is guaranteed before `b` are [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.order_of_handler_invocation) as followed:

- `strand.post(a)` happens before `strand.post(b)`.  As `post()` does not attempt to invoke the provided handler within `post()`, `a` is enqueued before `b`.
- `strand.post(a)` happens before `strand.dispatch(b)`, where `strand.dispatch(b)` is performed outside of a strand.  As `strand.dispatch(b)` occurs outside of a strand, `b` is queued as if by `post()`.  Thus, this reduces down to `strand.post(a)` happening before `strand.post(b)`.
- `strand.dispatch(a)` happens before `strand.post(b)`, where `strand.dispatch(a)` occurs outside of a strand.  As `strand.dispatch(a)` occurs outside of a strand, `a` is queued as if by `post()`.  Thus, this reduces down to `strand.post(a)` happening before `strand.post(b)`.
- `strand.dispatch(a)` happens before `strand.dispatch(b)`, where both are performed outside of the strand.  As neither occur within a strand, both handlers are enqueued as if by `post()`.  Thus, this reduces down to `strand.post(a)` happening before `strand.post(b)`.

The `io_service` [makes no guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734401/1053968) about the invocation order of handlers.  Additionally, the handler returned from `strand.wrap()` does not run within the context of a strand.  The example code simplifies to:

```cpp
auto wrapped_print1 = strand.wrap(&print1);
auto wrapped_print2 = strand.wrap(&print2);
timer1_.async_wait(wrapped_print1);
timer2_.async_wait(wrapped_print2);
```

If the `async_wait` operations complete at the same time, the `wrapped_print1` and `wrapped_print2` completion handlers will be posted into the `io_service` for deferred invocation.  As the `io_service` makes no guarantees on the invocation order, it may choose to invoke `wrapped_print1` first, or it may choose to invoke `wrapped_print2` first.  Both `wrapped_print` handlers are being invoked outside of the context of the strand in an unspecified order, resulting in `print1()` and `print2()` being enqueued into the strand in an unspecified order.

The unspecified order in which `wrapped_print` are invoked is why one is not guaranteed to observe an alternating pattern between the `print1` and `print2` handlers in the original example.  However, given the current implementation of the `io_service`'s internal scheduler, one will observe such a pattern.

Comment: What is the meaning of existence of `warp`? `warp` ,`post` and `dispatch` seems similar but `warp` doesn't ensure the handler execution order. And would you please explain what is `within the context of the strand` (any functions which calls strand.post has a scope for temporary variables, then what is `outside the context of the strand`?) and `outside the strand`? @Tanner Sansbury