# When do handlers for cancelled boost::asio handlers get to run?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

The boost docs [say](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html) that cancelled async connect, send and receive *finish immediately, and the handlers for cancelled operations will be passed the boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error.*

I would like to find out if the cancelled handler gets to run (and see the operation_aborted error) ***before*** other (non-cancelled, and newly scheduled) completion handlers run.

Here is the timeline that concerns me:

acceptHandler and readHandler are running on the same event loop and the same thread.

- time t0 - readHandler is running on oldConnectionSocket

  time t1 - acceptHandler runs

  time t2 - acceptHandler calls oldConnectionSocket.cancel

  time t3 - acceptHandler closes oldConnectionSocket

  time t4 - acceptHandler calls newConnectionSocket.async_read(...readHandler...)

  time t5 - readHandler is called (from which context?)

Is it possible at t5 for readHandler to be called in the newConnectionSocket context ***before*** it is called with the operation_aborted error in the oldConnectionSocket context?

Answer (score 5):

Cancelled operations will immediately post their handlers for deferred invocation.  However, the [`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) makes no guarantees on the invocation order of handlers.  Thus, the `io_service` could choose to invoke the ReadHandlers in either order.  Currently, only a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) specifies guaranteed ordering under certain conditions.

Within a completion handler, if the goal is to know which I/O object was associated with the operation, then consider constructing the completion handler so that it has an explicit handle to the I/O object.  This is often accomplished using any of the following:

- a custom functor
- `std::bind()` or `boost::bind()`
- a C++11 lambda

One common idiom is to have the I/O object be managed by a single class that inherits from [`boost::enable_shared_from_this<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html).  When a class inherits from `boost::enable_shared_from_this`, it provides a `shared_from_this()` member function that returns a valid `shared_ptr` instance to `this`.   A copy of the `shared_ptr` is passed to completion handlers, such as a capture-list in lambdas or passed as the instance handle to `boost::bind()`.  This allows for the handlers to know the I/O object on which the operation was performed, and causes the lifetime of the I/O object to be extended to at least as long as the handler.  See the Boost.Asio [asynchronous TCP daytime server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) tutorial for an example using this approach.

```cpp
class tcp_connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:

  // ...

  void start()
  {    
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, ...,
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

  void handle_write(
    const boost::system::error_code& error,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
  {
    // I/O object is this->socket_.
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

On the other hand, if the goal is to determine if one handler has executed before the other, then:

- the application will need to explicitly manage the state
- trying to manage multiple dependent call chains may be introducing unnecessary complexity and often indicates a need to reexamine the design
- custom handlers could be used to prioritize the order in which handlers are executed.  The Boost.Asio [Invocation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.invocation) example uses custom handlers that are added to a priority queue, which are then executed at a later point in time.

Comment: > However, the io_service makes no guarantees on the invocation order of handlers.

Is this still true if only one thread is executing `io_service::run()`?

Comment: Thank you Tanner for the detailed reply. strand will definitely work. Since my io_service runs in only one thread, and cancel is requested - and apparently happens - before the read is even scheduled, is it still possible for the read completion to run first?

Comment: @crmoore Yes.  The ordering of handlers within the `io_service` is unspecified, and the level of concurrency does not affect the ordering.

Comment: @StevenFaludi Yes, it is still possible.  A `strand` will guarantee the order of _handlers_, not the _operations_.  If `acceptHandler` closes `oldConnectionSocket`, initiates a read operation on `newConnectionSocket`, and later a read operation is initiated on `oldConnectionSocket`, then the order in which the read operations will be invoked and completed is unspecified.  Hence, the order in which the `ReadHandler`s will be invoked is unspecified.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28012491/1053968) answer for more details.