# async_wait handler class member with cancellation handling

Tags: c++, boost-asio

This works well:

```
class cStartSequence
{
void Tick()
{
// do something
}
void Wait()
{    
    myTimer->expires_from_now( 
        boost::posix_time::seconds( mySecs ) );
    myTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(
                            &cStartSequence::Tick,
                            this
                               ));
}
 ...
};
```

I want to be able to cancel the timer and have the handler do something different

```
void Tick( boost::system::error_code & ec )
{
  if( ! ec )
     // do something
  else
    // do something different
}
```

The question is how to modify the call to async_wait?

This does not compile

```
myTimer->async_wait(boost::bind(
                        &cStartSequence::Tick,
                        this,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error
                         ));
```

compiler complaint:

```
C:\Users\James\code\boost\v1_63\boost\bind\bind.hpp|319|error:
  no match for call to 
  '(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, pinmed::wrs::cStartSequence, boost::system::error_code&>) 
 (pinmed::wrs::cStartSequence*&, const boost::system::error_code&)'
```

I tried some variations on the async_wait parameters, but no luck.

boost:asio v1.63, windows 10, code::blocks v16.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Tick method takes a non-const reference. That's not ok (and doesn't satisfy the handler requirements). Use either

```
void Tick(boost::system::error_code const& ec);
```

Or maybe

```
void Tick(boost::system::error_code ec);
```

The first one is preferred by Asio author(s) for slightly obscurantist reasons (library-specific optimizations IIRC)

PS. For safe cancellation of deadline timers see also

- [cancel a deadline_timer, callback triggered anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192702/cancel-a-deadline-timer-callback-triggered-anyway/31195803#31195803)
- [Proper cleanup with a suspended coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739647/proper-cleanup-with-a-suspended-coroutine/26740429#26740429)

Comment: Using const wherever possible is a neat concept.  In practice, the compiler error messages are so vague that I must have wasted hours over the years staring at errors like this.  Why wont compilers come right out and tell us to look at problems with const!

Comment: It's not a matter of "throwing const in everywhere". (It makes a lot of sense to not expect a mutable lvalue reference by the way). Also, it should already point you at the static_assert in default configuration: [static assertion failed: WaitHandler type requirements not met](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3fcd416506f8e53). In the case of `bind` you don't get that, but it says [`error: binding reference of type 'boost::system::error_code&' to 'const boost::system::error_code' discards qualifiers`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e18ed6eba0e9bdc). I suggest to avoid `bind()`

Comment: You obviously speak compilerese much more fluently that I ever will.  I still think compile error messages could and should be much clearer when this sort of thing happens.  Avoiding bind?!?!  Probably the method I user more than any other.

Comment: Why? Don't you have c++11? Depending on where you mismatched the types, it even works better: [without const (static assertion)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/147f730dbd282e02) or [with const](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d34b1be21bfdee). If you don't want to need to be so fluent, avoid bind. It hides the real stuff in complicated machinery that just slows compilation down and doesn't add much (if anything)

Comment: No need to change all existing code (assuming it works).

Comment: This is likely not the place, but I would be interested to know how bind can be "avoided".  AFAIK it is the only way to call a class member function as an event handler. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html

Comment: It maybe the right place, but no longer the right time. Look up, 7 minutes ago