# Is Laravel task scheduler reliable?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

Suppose that I have task scheduled every midnight. Cron runs artisan schedule:run theoretically every minute. What will happen if the time 00:00 is somehow omitted? It seems to me that this might happen because of the system heavy load. Will scheduler notice that task has been omitted and run it at time 00:01?

Comment: BTW, these kinds of questions are not the kinds of questions that SO is for. SO is for specific programming problems. This is not a programming problem. Non-programming related Laravel questions would be better suited for the Laracasts Forums: https://laracasts.com/discuss

Comment: Year ago I asked similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733144/does-boost-asio-io-service-guarantee-execution-of-two-parallel-call-chains Is it also not a programming problem?

Comment: Technically no, but the moderators may have not caught it due to the code you included. Both questions are considered off topic according to the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @PatrickStephan I wouldn't say that this question is off-topic for SO. According to the set of [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions, I would guess this comes under bullet-point 3, software tools commonly used by programmers, in this case, a scheduler. I don't think a question is off-topic just because it doesn't include code (the only interpretation I have of your statement - "programming related"). But let me know what you think.

Comment: Setting aside the question of whether this is appropriate for SO, I think it would be a much better fit for Serverfault, which is part of the SE network of sites for server admins:  http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Over two years now, but still looks a relevant question. How does laravel know if a daily task is already run or not? Does it just check for the time 00:00 (there is a theoretical chance of missing it in this case), or does it log the details somewhere to check if it has already been run?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the scheduler (both as a part of Laravel and before it was part of the core) for well over a year now and I don't remember a time that it missed due to heavy load or unreliability. If it missed, it wasn't the schedular, but crontab itself.